# preg_match() matching partial strings with numbers using word boundaries in php

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I'm sure I'm overlooking something but I'm trying to do a simple match on an array of strings using php.

My array consists of comic titles followed by issue numbers

```
$comics = array('blah blah #13', 'more blah #3', 'more more blah #10');
```

I want to find the #1 issues and ignore the #10 and #13 issues.

my code

```
foreach ($comics as $child) {

 $kw = "#1"
 if(preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($kw)."\b/i", $child) {
  do some stuff
 }
 else {
       do other stuff
 }
}
```

I'm a novice at regular expresions but I'm sutre that the \b are like word boundries that will filter out the #10, #12 etc.   I tired a strpos() function but it was false matching #10.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach ($comics as $child) {
    $kw = "#1";
    if(preg_match("/$kw$/", $child) {
        //do some stuff
    }
    else {
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

PS: This code will only work if you have only 1 "#" in your string.

PS2: The last $ in the regex means "end of string" so if your string has something more before the number you should replace the "$" with an space.

Answer (score 0):

You can **avoid loop** and use **`preg_grep`** with following `regex`:

```
$comics = array('blah blah #13', 'more blah #1', 'more more blah #10');
print_r(preg_grep('/#1(?=\D|$)/', $comics));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => more blah #1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample titles, the issue number is the last part of the string. If that's always true, you can use the following regex:

```
/#1$/
```

Example:

```
if(preg_match("/#1$/", $child) {
    // #1 issue!
} else {
    // not the #1 issue
}
```

If the issue number can be followed by additional text, which is hinted at by your use of `\b`, you can slightly modify the regex you currently have by stating no numbers can follow the `#1`:

```
$kw = "#1[^0-9]"
if(preg_match("/\b" . $kw . "\b/i", $child) {
```

If you do this, it can allow standard word-characters (such as `a-z` to follow `#1`, but not another number so you'll ignore #10 or #153, for example). You can continue to expand the ignore-list by adding any characters that can't follow the `#1` with something similar to `$kw = "#1[^0-9a-z.,]";`, etc.

It might be more of-interest to specify a set of characters that *can* follow the `#1` as well (just the regex here, for brevity):

```
\b#1(?:[.;, ]|$)
```

This regex will take any `#1` followed by a period, semi-colon, comma or space, *or* the end of the line. This would be useful if you do have a list of characters that can follow the `#1` but you want to prohibit a wider-set of characters.

Comment: Yes I failed to mention that the issue number could be followed by other text.  Thank you for both solutions I'll give them a try.